# Sending email with body of message being the contents of a cell, including new-line formatting?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to send an email with the body of the message consisting of the contents of a text box. So far I've tried pulling in the text box through vba as a string, but that takes away all the new-lines formatting. Is there a way to get the text box contents exactly as they are into the email?

```
Sub Send_Email()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Dim title As String, emailto As String
Dim texts As String

title = Range("email_subject").Value
emailto = Range("email_to").Value
texts = Worksheets("Input").Shapes("TextBox 2").TextFrame.Characters.Text

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = emailto
    .Subject = title
    .HTMLBody = texts
    .display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: int HTML, `<br>` means new line. Save you `texts` value as a html file, open in broswer and keep refining till you see expected result.  Then update your vba to convert  `texts` to html.

Answer (score 0):

Please find an example below that might help with your question. You will have global variable that will hold information from excel worksheet and use them in the email. Whithout a image on how your data looks cannot really guess what you are trying to do. Maybe you can separete the text in different cells that way you can loop throught and put them in different variables and you can construct your email in the `SendEmail` procedure. Or if you have the same text and it doesn't change you can make it as per the below example.

```
Option Explicit
Dim titleName As String
Dim firstName As String
Dim lastName As String
Dim fullName As String
Dim clientEmail As String
Dim ccEmail As String
Dim bccEmail As String
Dim emailMessage As String

Sub GenerateInfo()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim cRow As Long

    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    With WS
        lrow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For cRow = 2 To lrow
            If Not .Range("L" & cRow).value = "" Then
                titleName = .Range("D" & cRow).value
                firstName = .Range("E" & cRow).value
                lastName = .Range("F" & cRow).value
                fullName = firstName & " " & lastName
                clientEmail = .Range("L" & cRow).value

                Call SendEmail

                .Range("Y" & cRow).value = "Yes"
                .Range("Y" & cRow).Font.Color = vbGreen

            Else
                .Range("Y" & cRow).value = "No"
                .Range("Y" & cRow).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next cRow
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Process completed!", vbInformation

End Sub
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Dim sigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim insertPhoto As String
    Dim photoSize As String

    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    sigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Marius.htm"

    If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    insertPhoto = "C:\Users\marius\Desktop\Presale.jpg" 'Picture path
    photoSize = "<img src=""cid:Presale.jpg""height=400 width=400>" 'Change image name here

    emailMessage = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Dear " & titleName & " " & fullName & "," & _
                    "<p>I hope my email will find you very well." & _
                    "<p>Our <strong>sales preview</strong> starts on Thursday the 22nd until Sunday the 25th of November." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to welcoming you into the store to shop on preview.<p>" & _
                    "<p> It really is the perfect opportunity to get some fabulous pieces for the fast approaching festive season." & _
                    "<p>Please feel free to contact me and book an appointment." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to seeing you then." & _
                    "<p>" & photoSize & _
                    "<p>Kind Regards," & _
                    "<br>" & _
                    "<br><strong>Marius</strong>" & _
                    "<br>Assistant Store Manager" & _
                    "<p>"


    With outlookMail
        .To = clientEmail
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "PRIVATE SALE"
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .Attachments.Add insertPhoto, 1, 0
        .HTMLBody = emailMessage & Signature 'Including photo insert and signature
        '.HTMLBody = emailMessage & Signature 'Only signature
        .Importance = 2
        .ReadReceiptRequested = True
        .Display
        .Send

    End With

    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set outlookMail = Nothing
End Sub
Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```